# Difference in recursion handling between languages

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, recursion, lisp

Here are some snippets in different languages.

Function `double` in question is taken from SICP, ex. 1.41.

Lisp:

```
(define (double f) (lambda (x) (f (f x))))
(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
(((double (double double)) inc) 5)
```

Python:

```
def double(f):
  def result(x):
    return f(f(x))
  return result

def inc(x):
  return x + 1

double(double(double(inc)))(5)
```

Javascript:

```
var double = function(f) {
  return function(x) { return f(f(x)) };
};

var inc = function(x) { return x + 1  };

(double(double(double(inc))))(5);
```

Ruby:

```
double = lambda {|f| lambda {|x| f[f[x]] } }
inc = lambda {|x| x+1 }
double[double[double[inc]]][5]
```

If I am not insane, these functions should do the same thing and return the same result.
However, lisp version returns 21 whereas others return 13. Can you explain that difference to me? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How you call the functions in the scheme code is different from the others. The equivalent python would be:

```
double(double(double))(inc)(5)
```

In words, the scheme code creates a function that applies another function 16 times, and applies that function to `inc`. The python creates functions that apply `inc` 8 times; the others work the same as the python.

The difference might be a bit clearer if you introduce names for the intermediate steps. In scheme:

```
(define quadruple (double double))
(define hexadecuple (double quadruple)) ; hexadecuple may not actually be a word... 
(define add16 (hexadecuple inc))
(add16 5)
```

I hope that's correct syntax; it's been a while since I've done anything with scheme.

In python:

```
add2 = double(inc)
add4 = double(add2)
add8 = double(add4)
add8(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness' sake, here's how a fixed Ruby version would look like:

```
double = ->f { ->x { f.(f.(x)) }}
inc    = ->x { x.succ }

double.(double.(double)).(inc).(5)
```